# i have created a circle from lines in opengl but it shows holes at outer edges

Tags: opengl

I had drawn a circle in opengl using lines.But it shows a pattern of holes at outer edges.
I want to fill this holes without reducing the radius and increasing the number of samples.
This is my code:

```
void drawcirc(float xi,float yj,float r1,int num1)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2f(0,0);
    for (int i=0;i<=num1;i++)           
    {                       
    float theta=2.0f*3.141592f*float(i)/float(num1);
    float x1=r1*cosf(theta);
    float y1=r1*sinf(theta);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2f(0,0);
    glVertex2f(xi+x1,yj+y1);
    glEnd();
    sleep(5000);
    glFlush();
    }
}
```

then function call `drawcirc(0, 0, 0.6, 1250);`

what to do? this is my o/p with holes at outer edges.

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 2):

Okay, well you're not really drawing a circle. GL_LINES will go from point to point until the primitive ends

You draw a line from 0,0 to a point on the rim of the circle + the offset you give the function.

So you're drawing the spokes of a wheel essentially, the holes at the edge are the gaps between the spokes.

Answer (score 1):

AlecTeal already answered what is going on. I give you the fix:

```
#include <math.h>

void drawFilledCircle(float xi,float yj,float r1,int num1)
{
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glVertex2f(0,0);
    for(int i = 0; i <= num1; i++)           
    {                       
        float theta = 2.0f*M_PI * float(i)/float(num1);
        float x1 = r1*cosf(theta);
        float y1 = r1*sinf(theta);
        glVertex2f(xi+x1,yj+y1);
    }
    glEnd();
}

void drawCircle(float xi,float yj,float r1,int num1)
{
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for(int i = 0; i < num1; i++)           
    {                       
        float theta = 2.0f*M_PI * float(i)/float(num1);
        float x1 = r1*cosf(theta);
        float y1 = r1*sinf(theta);
        glVertex2f(xi+x1,yj+y1);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

A few hints:

- Never put glFlush, glClear, sleep or similar into function intended to draw a geometrical shape. You want to be able to call such functions from higher level drawing code and such calls are highly disruptive.
- glBegin and glEnd are deprecated, their use has been discouraged for well over 15 years now. Better use vertex arrays.
- If you must use glBegin/glEnd put them outside of the loop, not inside it.

Comment: can u suggest me how to remove this holes.

Comment: @user3839676: I did. Look at the code I wrote, what it does different from yours and you'll see. Hint: GL_LINE_LOOP drawing mode will connect the last line segment with the first, useful for drawing outlines. To draw a filled circle you can not use lines drawn from the center. And you should not use lines at all. OpenGL has a perfectly fine working filled triangle primitive; even better yet, there is GL_TRIANGLE_FAN which draws triangles all having their corner at some common center point.

Comment: I have tried triangle fan and I know it works but my concern is not to draw a filled circle but to remove that holes with some hole filling algorithm and the fact that I cannot increase the sample size i.e., num1 in my program...........In short looking for some hole filling algorithm.

Comment: @user3839676: That's not how OpenGL works. OpenGL is a drawing API concerned with putting points, lines and triangles to a framebuffer, applying textures and shaders doing it. "Filling holes" is a terribly unspecific request. Do you want to *clipped flood fill*? Or maybe you want to *erode and dilate by colvolution* the image. Two viable approaches but neither is directly supported by OpenGL. flood fill doesn't cater very good to the highly parallelized processing in OpenGL, but writing an erosion-dilation convolution shader as a postprocessing step is doable.

Comment: @user3839676: The really important thing to care about OpenGL is the outcome. Always choose the simplest method that will produce the desired result. In your case its a filled circle => a triangle fan it is. If you however want a filled circle with that line pattern in it: First draw a filled circle, switch colors, then draw the line pattern; by making use of stencil operations and reversing the order you may be able to get out a bit more fillrate.

Comment: yaa! post processing is a better way and what I am trying to do now is to locate those empty pixels somehow and fill it with drawpixel function.

Comment: can u help me with some drawpixel example because I am finding it really hard, of how to define the array of pixels for that and what that 3D array mean.

Comment: @user3839676: In OpenGL there is no such thing as draw pixel. That's simply now how OpenGL is meant to work and meant to be used. Your best bet would be a fragment shader that ingests the image with holes and applies the an erosion convolution matrix ([0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]) on the image. But I'm really thinking you're barking up the wrong tree here. You ask for filling out the holes. What is the long term goal you're trying to achieve? Just a filled circle: Then just draw that. Something different? Then please tell, us, because there might be a better method.